# D3 - Updating a grouped bar chart with a varying number of bars

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

Forewarning: I am a D3 novice.

[Here is the grouped bar chart](http://josh.apos.tl/d3/) I'm working with. The only buttons that work are those labelled 'Gender' and 'Age', but this is enough to illustrate the functionality I'm asking about.

There are a few issues that I'm having, the main issue being that I'm unable to properly update the bar groups. Specifically, I'm unsure of how to properly .select and .remove the elements from the previously selected category and populate the chart with data from the new category. Right now, I've got it working somewhat, but what ends up happening is the elements are endlessly duplicated within the DOM, which becomes apparent when looking at the text labels.

Another issue is that the bars from multiple sets of data sometimes appear, but I suspect this is related to the issue described above.

A minor issue I'm also having is in figuring out how to properly centre the text labels against the bars that they are labelling. I know how to do this with a traditional bar chart, but I'm confused about how I would create a function that would position these correctly.

Thanks in advance!